# How to grepcode java files in gitlab

Tags: java, gitlab, grepcode

I need a grepcode tool-like, so far we're testing gitlab and I was wondering if it's possible by any way to browse class, see class hierarchy in gitlab like in grepcode.com?

Or maybe, is it actually possible to have a tool like grepcode.com installed locally? Or does it exist a version control system which does that?

Comment: Javadoc? Or you want to see source code?

Comment: I want to see the code, just like http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#StringUtils

Comment: Right, and your IDE is capable of that if you attach sources for the code. Gitlab and other version control tools hold more than just Java, so I doubt that would be a reasonable tool to have on the site(s)

Comment: You're right, but I need it the tool to be online

Comment: Alright, well, as I said, not really possible by those sites you mentioned. I'm not aware of any, and requests for software tools and libraries are off topic for StackOverflow, so best of luck to you